# iPhone UIButton provide different inset values for highlighted state

Tags: iphone, uibutton, textlabel

I want my titleLabel text move a little down on button tap (i.e. I want to give different inset values for highlighted and default states).

I have custom button background images and the button goes down in highlighted state image but the text on it stands at the same place so it gives a bad effect and looks like the text is seperated from button.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to put your text on the button's background image.

If you can't do that for some reason you can try to add `IBAction` on `Button down` and adjust `button.titleLabel.frame`.